# i am going to migrate a table in laravel but having a problem

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

when i try to migrate 
... php artisan migrate ...
it says 
...

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException

could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where tabl
e_schema = forproject and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

at E:\xampp\htdocs\forpractice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databas
e\Connection.php:671

```
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll
 format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make th
is exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the databa
se's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
    671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|
```

1   E:\xampp\htdocs\forpractice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databa
se\Connectors\Connector.php:70

> PDOException::("could not find driver")

2   E:\xampp\htdocs\forpractice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databa
se\Connectors\Connector.php:70

> PDO::__construct()
>   ...

what i need to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `.env` file and look for `DB_CONNECTION` key. It should contain one of - MySQL, pgsql or sqlite.

Secondly, ensure the particular DB client is installed on your system. For example, if you specified mysql, ensure mysql is installed on your system